# creating selection string as a parameter to a cursor constructor

Tags: java, android, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I got this piece of code in a project I'm working on, in the implementation of **public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)**:

```
Uri baseUri=Events.CONTENT_URI;
final String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[] {Events.CALENDAR_ID, 
                                                Events.ORGANIZER, 
                                                Events.TITLE, 
                                                Events.EVENT_LOCATION, 
                                                Events.DTSTART, 
                                                Events.DTEND, 
                                                Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE,
                                                Events.EVENT_END_TIMEZONE,
                                                Events.DURATION,
                                                Events.ALL_DAY,
                                                Events.RRULE,
                                                Events.RDATE,
                                                };
String selection = "((" + "this.isCalendarAvailable("+Events.CALENDAR_ID+") = ?)) AND ("
                        + "TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(Long.parseLong("+Events.DTSTART+",10)) = ?))";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"true",String.valueOf(selectedDate.getTimeInMillis())};
return new CursorLoader(this,baseUri,EVENT_PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, Events.DTSTART);
```

I wanted to get the details (specified in EVENT_PROJECTION) of all events that are found on available calendars (according to  the boolean method isCalendarAvailable) and that start on selectedDate.

I tried to do that by initializing String selection as above, but it seems that it is not possible due to a misunderstanding the way this string should be written.

I already know that i can use "AND", "OR" and "=?".
But is there any other syntax rules for a string to be used as a parameter for cursorLoader constructor??
If not, is there any way for selecting what i need from the Uri according to some methods (as I tried above)?

Thanks a lot in advance